# Find a basis for every EigenSpace of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

To find the EigenSpace of matrix A, will the row swap affect the results?

A = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&1&0\\0&1&4&5\\0&0&3&1\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}

I computed that the characteristic polynomial is (λ-1)(λ-2)(λ-2)(λ-3).

For λ = 2, let matrix B = λI - A = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1&-1&0\\0&1&-4&-5\\0&0&-1&-1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

For B, the RREF can be \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
OR
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&-1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Either of the above is correct form of RREF(B).

When computing the EigenSpace of A, I got
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}

OR

\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix};\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}

The difference lies in [1 -1 0 1] and [1 0 -1 1]. I can see that it comes from a row swap. But does this matter?

Comment: Your second matrix is not in reduced row-echelon form.

Comment: the eigenspace of eigenvalue $\lambda$ is just the kernel of $A-\lambda I$. You only need a vector as basis for each eigenspace except the case for $\lambda=2$ because it appear twice in the diagonal. In each case the system of equations are not so complicate to solve.

Answer (score 0):

They are both incorrect, the method that will work is to determine the eigenvectors first. $[1\ 0\ 0\ 0]^T$ is correct but the second one needs to be: $[0\ 1\ -1\ 1]^T$ (this doesn't depend on the two matrices you have above). You can check if it is an eigenvector by multiplying it with the matrix and see if you get the eigenvector back multiplied with the corresponding eigenvector.
The basis of the EigenSpace of A for EigenValue $\lambda = 2$ is:
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$
The EigenSpace is any linear combination of the vectors from the basis.